# Why can't I make a RunOnce entry in the Windows Registry using TRegistry and Delphi?

Tags: delphi, runonce

I am using the following code to try to make a RunOnce entry:

```
program RunOnceTest;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Registry, Windows;

var
  R: TRegistry;
begin
  try
    WriteLn('Testing RunOnStartup.......');


    R := TRegistry.Create;
    try
      R.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
      R.LazyWrite := False;
      R.OpenKey('Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce', True) ;
      R.WriteString('this', 'that') ;
      R.CloseKey;
    finally
      R.free;
    end;

    WriteLn('Test Finished');

    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

I run the app, and it executes.

However, there is no entry at:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce

in my registry.  Do I need administrator privileges?  What else do I need to do?

ADDED:  I should explain better and really ask a question about what I am trying to do.  I am trying to get my app to run automatically at startup.  Lot's of applications do this without appearing to require admin privileges.  What is the normal way to do this?

Comment: For writing to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE you will need administrator privileges, yes.

Comment: Which OS version do you use? And yes, you need admin privileges. If Vista/Win7 - try right click - run as administrator.

Comment: It's Windows 7/64.  And so I guess I'll now have to figure out how to get user privileges in my app, eh?  Great.....

Comment: Nah, not that hard and you get used to it.

Comment: I've added more info to really ask what I want to do:  How do I get my Delphi app to "Run on startup" like a ton of other apps I have?

Comment: @Nick When you were at Embarcadero, did the developers run with UAC enabled on their dev machines?

Comment: Okay, found the problem:  I really only want the thing to run for Current User, so I need HKEY_CURRENT_USER not HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

Comment: So what is the proper etiquette?  I found the answer -- is it considered okay to answer my own question after you fine people helped me so ably?

Comment: If your answer is not part of any existing answer then yes, answer it yourself and accept it.

Comment: Nick, if you have an answer to the original question you asked, then go ahead and add it as your own answer. It sounds like you have an answer to a different question, though. (Perhaps it's to the question you *should* have asked.)

Comment: If you want your app to run at every windows start up I wouldn't use RunOnce cause they get deleted after they run, well, once... The Run key is there to be used for apps that need to run every time Windows starts.

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with TRegistry, but if you aren't getting errors then your app may be virtualized. You don't want this I can assure you.

Comment: @Nick, do you really need to ensure it forces the run section every time your app runs? My approach would be to create this registry key in the installer of your application and then make the installer require admin rights. That way it is added to your registry without your application needing elevation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all you need to have admin rights to write there. Mostly it's just installers that write to this key and they generally run elevated.  Add this to your application manifest if that's the way you want to go:

```
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
  <security>
    <requestedPrivileges>
      <requestedExecutionLevel
        level="requireAdministrator"
        uiAccess="false"/>
    </requestedPrivileges>
  </security>
</trustInfo>
```

If this write to `HKLM` is being made from an application that doesn't otherwise need elevation then please consider separating out the write to `HKLM` into a separate process so that only that registry key write needs elevation. This is best practise with UAC.

The other thing that might bite you is that your Delphi app will be 32 bit and so subject to registry redirection. Accesses of `HKLM\Software` will get redirected to `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node`.

On a 64 bit system I think you should endeavour to write to `HKLM\Software` and so you'll need to disable redirection. Do this by including [`KEY_WOW64_64KEY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384129%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) in the `Access` property of your `TRegistry` instance.

Windows will merge both views of the registry when it processes `Run` and `RunOnce` keys but your application will leave clearer trails if you write to the 64 bit area of the registry for this particular key.

Comment: Do you know if RunOnce works in both views of the registry or only in the native one? So would it work if he wrote to the 32-bit view?

Comment: @Heinrich I believe Windows merges both views of that key. It certainly does so for `HKLM\Software\...\Run`. But I would always prefer to write to the native key. My reasoning is that the key is interpreted by the system shell and the system shell is 64 bit.

Comment: Reasonable thought. Not merging would also break compatibility with applications not taking care of writing to the "other side".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, administrator privileges are required to modify HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

Three possibilities:

1. Don't use that key and find another way.
2. [Read here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163486.aspx) An
   app manifest might be the way to go (section "Marking Required Privileges Using an Application Manifest"). This will ask the user for consent when he starts the app. That's the easy way.
3. Let the user run your application without admin privileges and put the code requiring them in another executable. Run this on demand and only if the user requested it. That's the preferable way.

**Edit** for the added part:

Have you tried using HKEY_CURRENT_USER instead? This runs the app for the current user only but you don't need to have admin privileges to write to the registry.